# Create Temporary Page

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

can someone point me to the right direction

I need a code to dynamically create a temporary Web Pop-up Page which I'll declare the HTML Content in ASP.NET Using VB

reason for this function is that I am trying to make Application Form printer and I need to print the current page with the

```
<script>window.print();</script>
```

Comment: VB.NET to ASP.net?

Comment: ASP.NET, I am using VB on my code behind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could generate the entire HTML as string and then use as below:

```
window.open("data:text/html;charset=utf-8,<head></head><body><h3>Test Document</h3></body><script>window.print();</script>");
```

Basically,

```
window.open("data:text/html;charset=utf-8," + YOUR_HTML + "<script>window.print();</script>");
```

Copy paste the below script in a browser to test:

```
data:text/html;charset=utf-8,<head></head><body><h3>Test Document</h3></body><script>window.print();</script>
```

**== Updates ==** 
*Aspx.vb Code*

```
Dim htmlText As String = "<head></head><bod‌​y><h3>Test Document</h3></body>".Normalize()
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "tempWindow", "<script>openTempWindow('" + htmlText + "')</script>", False)
```

*Aspx Code*

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function openTempWindow(content) {
        var win = window.open("");
        win.document.write(content);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: it does show a new tab but there's nothing on the page

Comment: It should have the words "Test Document" in it. I tested this in Chrome and FireFox

Comment: ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "script", "window.open('data:text/html;charset=utf-8,<head></head><body><h3>Test Document</h3></body>','popup_window', 'width=300,height=100,left=100,top=100,resizable=yes');", True)

Comment: I think I figure out the reason why the code won't run, when I remove the CSS line on the HTML Script your code works

Comment: do you know how can I declare style='text-align:right;' on your code?

Comment: 2 Ways add <style> tag and use in html tag with class attribute or directly add as a style attribute in the desired html tag. You can post your code as a new question, add a link to this question. It will be easy to point issues and fix by looking at the code you have finally written.

Comment: never mind I already figure out how to do it, your code works great thanks you so much for your time

Comment: Hi I just notice something on my page, the Image is missing from the printout

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by manipulating the [response](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.response(v=vs.110).aspx).  This is one way to *dinamically* create an HTML document. For example:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<html>
<body>
    <h1>Something to print</h1>
</body>
<script>window.print();</script>
</html>")
```

In order to make it a popup window, in your *base page* you can implement [`window.open()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp) function after, lets say, a button click.  For example:

```
window.open("../pageReturningDynamicHTML.aspx?someParam=someValue")
```

In the provided link you can find more examples on how to open a window as popup with settings as sizes and more.

Comment: thank you for your response but that won't create a temporary Pop-up Page, instead it will add the HTML script below my current HTML Structure